# Object interaction through object-specific method

Tags: swift, function, methods

I am trying to produce a function that involves a unique initiating object, a target object and a path object, in which the initiating and target objects are of the same class `A`, and the path object is of a different class `B`. The ideal output of this specific function should be `input A1, A2 to B1`; however, the result is `input , to  B1`:

```
import UIKit
var interA = ""
var interB = ""
class A {
//Where any unique unit in A must interact with any other unique unit in A through a unique path B.
    var name = "name"
}
class B {
    var path = "path"
}
func action(user: A, medium: B, target: A) {
    interA = user.name
    interB = target.name
    print(medium.path)
}
var A1 = A()
A1.name = "A1"
var A2 = A()
A2.name = "A2"
var B1 = B()
B1.path = "input \(interA), \(interB) to B1" //String simplification of multivariate function f(AI, AJ)
action(user: A1, medium: B1, target: A2) //Should show up as "input A1, A2 to B1"
```

Any solutions to the problem or more simplified methods of approach are appreciated. (Future inputs to this function should ideally include all the possible permutations of `AI`, `AJ` and `BK` for positive integers `I`, `J` and `K`.)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the path variable before `action` has a chance to update the user/target values.  The replacement of the "\()" values happens once when the string is evaluated, not dynamically.

Comment: How could I modify the function to dynamically update variables?

Comment: Put `medium.path = "input \(interA), \(interB) to B1"` inside `action` after you set the variables and before `print`.

Comment: That would work if all `B`  paths equal `"input \(interA), \(interB) to B1"`, but not if `B2.path = "\(interA) + \(interB)"`, `B3.path = `B3(\(interA))` ...` etc. How would I be able to dynamically update variables while maintaining a unique, object `A`-dependent path for `B`?

Comment: Something has to know the path format that an object needs.  Whatever that thing is needs to also know when variables change and **then** tell the object to update its path.  (Or, the object knows its own path format and updates the path when variables change.)